# Unable to vagrant box add laravel/homestead (errno 60 / SSL read)

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5.1, homestead

Basically I got this error seconds after I trigger
`vagrant box add laravel/homestead` in my terminal.

[image]

What's more interesting, after second failed attempt, the error message is a little bit different (as you see).

**Error number 60** is somehow related to SSL. Since I'm running this command via terminal, I really have no idea how to investigate this issue. Can somebody give me any hints? May it be related to poor wireless internet connection?

```
slick-mac:~ slick$ vagrant version
Installed Version: 1.7.4
Latest Version: 1.7.4

You're running an up-to-date version of Vagrant!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm deliberately posting this as an answer because probably I've found solution. So far it's still downloading.

What I did:

**1. I removed temp stuff**

`rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/`

**2. I started the download again**

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

So far it's still OK despite of my slow internet connection. If that won't work I will try Frederic's solution.

**EDIT:**

After 80% it failed. (no --insecure) param.

Answer (score 3):

If you get an SSL issue, you can try to add the box using the *insecure* option

```
vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead
```

> `--insecure` When present, SSL certificates won't be verified if the URL is an HTTPS URL

Comment: You were right Frederic. Your answer (--insecure) combined with deleting content of `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/` was the solution.

Comment: excellent ! good to know I never faced this issue so was not 100% sure this option would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

These SSL related issues are not from client side. It is originated from the source. We can do nothing from our side. I have tried with Windows OS, Mac OS X and manual download with many browsers and even with downloaders, no luck. Somehow I managed to download with mobile browser on 4G. I was wondering why not upload this to place everyone can download.

You can find a mirror [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiUDyf4p8pdZHpPUGhwVkJ2VWc/view?usp=sharing) on my Google Drive. It is a copy of laravel/homestead 0.5.0. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Adding `--insecure` argument, specifying url, `https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`, and removing the tmp file beforehand did not work for me.

Brutely repeating download attempts to download did however. Thus, in my case, nothing to do with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

what **Worked** for me was emptying the temp first then running the following command:

```
vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead
```

it looks like after failing once ,it couldn't resume correctly until the temp was emptied .

hope this helps.